# Understanding oracle database data access mechanisms

Tags: database, oracle

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79266/how-do-you-interpret-a-querys-explain-plan):

> Full table scans, index range scans,
>   fast full index scans, nested loops,
>   merge join, hash joins etc. are simply
>   access mechanisms that must be
>   understood by the analyst

Can someone explain each one and also provide where I can do some further reading on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more on the joins, I would recommend reading some articles from Jonathan Lewis:

- [Nested Loop Join](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/joins-nlj/)
- [Hash Join](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/joins-hj/)
- [Merge Join](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/joins-mj/)

For more info on reading Execution Plans and interpreting what they mean I would recommend the book:

[Troubleshooting Oracle Performance by Christian Antognini](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599179)

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#i21299

Chapter 11

Section 11.3 Overview of Joins

Answer (score 1):

For starters I recommend the [relevant section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/sqllangu.htm#sthref917) of Oracle Database Concepts.

If you want more detail, you can refer to the [Performance Tuning Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#i82080) as Robert indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Great questions. I found these articles quite helpful for understanding these specific topics.

[Oracle HASH Joins:](http://www.confio.com/logicalread/oracle-11g-hash-joins-mc02/#.UZ-gE-uPUQI)

[Oracle INDEX-MERGE Joins:](http://www.confio.com/logicalread/oracle-11g-index-merge-joins-mc02/#.UZ-fauuPUQI)

Comment: it would be best if you can provide relevant links for the question (for full table scans, index range scans, etc). The site that you linked has a lot of content other than Joins, it is difficult navigating all of those and finding out which ones are related to the question.