# Total cost of a query through Oracle's explain plan

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am a bit new to Oracle and I am have a question regarding Oracle's explain plan. I have used the 'auto-trace' feature for a particular query.

SQL> SELECT * from myTable;
11 rows selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1233351234

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |    11 |   330 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTABLE|    11 |   330 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is if I want to calculate the 'total' cost of this query, is it 6 (3+3) or its only 3. Suppose I had a larger query with more steps in the plan, do I have to add up all the values in the cost column to get the total cost or is it the first value (ID=0) that is the total cost of a query?

Answer (score 11):

Cost is 3, the plan is shown as a hierarchy, with the cost of the sub-components already included in the parent components.

Comment: my pleasure

I should add that the parent costs are not _just_ the sum of the child costs, since the parent operation has some non-zero cost as well.  Often that cost is minimal for many types of non-leaf operations, so it effectively appears as zero, as is the case here.

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to take a look at some of the responses to:
[How do you interpret a query's explain plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79266/how-do-you-interpret-a-querys-explain-plan)